# Finding the PMF of a certain random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

I am self-learning probability theory. For the following problem, I would like someone to verify if my approach and solution is sound and correct.

> Exercise 3.3.4 - Grimmett,Stirzaker: Let $S_k$ be the set of positive integers whose base-$10$ exapansion contains exactly $k$ elements(so that for example, $1024 \in S_4$). A fair coin is tossed until the first head appears, and we write $T$ for the number of tosses required. We pick a random element, $N$ say, from $S_T$, each such element having equal probability. What is the mass function of $N$?

***Solution.***

The probability mass function of the time until the first head appears is given by,

$P(T=1) = \frac{1}{2}$

$P(T=2) = \frac{1}{4}$

$P(T=3) = \frac{1}{8}$

$P(T=k) = \frac{1}{2^k}$

The conditional probability distribution of $N$ is given by,

$P(N=i \vert T=k) = \frac{1}{9 \cdot 10^{k-1}}$

By the law of total probability, summing over all $k$, we have:

\begin{align*}
P(N=i) &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}\cdot\frac{1}{9\cdot 10^{k-1}}\\
&= \frac{10}{9}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{20^k}\\
&= \frac{10}{9}\frac{(1/20)}{1-(1/20)}\\
&= \frac{10}{9}\cdot \frac{1}{19}\\
&= \frac{10}{171}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are claiming that $N$ is uniformly distributed over $\Bbb N^+$ ... so... nope.  There's something awry.

---

You have $\mathsf P(T\,{=}\,k)= 2^{-k}\;\mathbf 1_{k\in[[1..\infty)]}\\\mathsf P(N\,{=}\,i\mid T\,{=}\,k)= 9^{-1}\cdot 10^{1-k}\;\mathbf 1_{i\in[[1..9\cdot10^{k-1}]]}$

Thus when given $N=i$, the supported values of $T$ must be $k$ such that $i\leqslant 9\cdot 10^{k-1}$.  (eg. If $i$ is a $2$ digit number, $k$ must be at least $2$.)

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(N\,{=}\,i)&=\dfrac{10}{9}\mathbf 1_{i\in\Bbb N^+}\cdot\hspace{-8ex}\sum_{\hspace{8ex} k = \lceil1+\log(i/9)\rceil}^\infty\dfrac{1}{20^k}\\[3ex]&=\begin{cases}\dfrac{10}{171}&:& i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}\\\dfrac{1}{342}&:&i\in\{10,...,99\}\\ &\vdots\\ \dfrac{10}{171\cdot 20^{n-1}}&:&i\in\{10^{n-1},...,10^n-1\}\end{cases} \end{align}$$